# How can I get Ubuntu version using Java?

Tags: java, ubuntu

I'm trying to get Ubuntu version using Java, but there is a problem.

When using the `System.getProperty("os.version")`, it's return the kernel version.

- How can I get release version like "14.04", etc?

Comment: In java  `os.name,os.arch,os.version` available . May be below answer could help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run any terminal command (like `lsb_release -a`) inside a Java class  with

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("lsb_release -a");
```

And parse the output

EDIT: Clear solution

```
String[] args = new String[] {"/bin/bash", "-c", "lsb_release -r", "with", "args"};
Process proc = new ProcessBuilder(args).start();
```

Note: You need to use lsb_release -r to get only the version.

Comment: FSG lsb_release v2.0+ prints certain LSB (Linux Standard Base) and Distribution information, like release version. And it should be present on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a snippet to achieve your goal:

```
String version = (new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((new ProcessBuilder("lsb_release", "-rs")).start().getInputStream()))).readLine();
System.out.println(version);
```

Those two lines display something like that:

```
14.04
```

Answer (score 0):

Java has following system properties defined in its documentation for operating systems but none will work for your case.

`"os.arch"  -Operating system architecture
"os.name"   -Operating system name
"os.version"-Operating system version`

You will have to execute `lsb_release -a` command using java code like this.

```
 Runtime.getRuntime().exec("lsb_release -a");
```

This will give you output like following.

> No LSB modules are available.
>
> Distributor ID:    LinuxMint
>
> Description:   Linux Mint 18.1 Serena
>
> Release:   18.1
>
> odename:   serena

You can parse it and get the output.